# How is create-react-app showing lint errors with "npm start"?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, eslint, webpack-dev-server

While using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) (with no customizations), and invoking `npm start`, it appears that linting occurs on individual files as they are saved, and any error or warning output is shown:

[image]

I'm trying to reverse-engineer how this is working, but am stuck.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with [husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) and/or [lint-staged](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lint-staged) but I haven't been able to replicate this behavior in my (non-sharable) playpen.

I understand how to setup and configure eslint (and I can see errors/warnings when invoking `eslint` directly), and I've been able to run linting around my Git actions (i.e., `pre-commit`) using husky and lint-staged, so I feel that I'm close to solving this puzzle, but I still don't get any of this type of output when I invoke [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/).

What tooling is used to get eslint output to appear during the create-react-app `npm start` command?

Comment: Isn't this simply eslint-loader?

Comment: Ah! Yep, that was it! I was over-thinking it. Thank you...please post this as an answer so I can mark this question resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the feature of [`eslint-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-loader) which is added to the webpack configuration in create-react-app.

```
{
  test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
  enforce: 'pre',
  use: [{
    options: {
      cache: true,
      formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
      eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
      resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
      // @remove-on-eject-begin
      ignore: isExtendingEslintConfig,
      baseConfig: isExtendingEslintConfig
        ? undefined
        : {
            extends: [require.resolve('eslint-config-react-app')],
          },
      useEslintrc: isExtendingEslintConfig,
      // @remove-on-eject-end
    },
    loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
  }],
  include: paths.appSrc
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/edc671eeea6b7d26ac3f1eb2050e50f75cf9ad5d/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L359)

Comment: The loader eslint-loader will be deprecated soon, could use [eslint-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-webpack-plugin) instead.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular and react project with npm module, you can use "**npm run lint -- --fix**" that will solve the all the possible lint errors and then you check with **ng lint** command post the above fix command runs